# Quad Junctions. Why are some not working the same as identical looking one nearby?

Tags: edges, knife-tool, looping

NOTE: as per Moonboots helpful suggestions. Here is the .Blend file for this problem:   [image]

Hello all I am trying to learn Blender. I've read lots and watched lots of videos and kinda understand the need for Quad Junctions to 'steer' the edge loops to make sharp edges in the model etc.

I'm currently trying to make a fairly basic car bonnet/hood. It is almost all flat, except there is a vent in the middle with a rim running around it like so:[image]

So I traced the shape of the bonnet with vertices, keeping it lightweight and simple. I then 'Inset' the inner vent area (without boundaries) and it all seemed to be working fine.

But from the tutorials I watched/read, I gather that I will need a supporting edge-loop around either side (so inner and outer of the actual extruded rim). As stated above the inner one 'Inset' worked great but for the outer one I couldn't use Inset, and so I followed some instruction video and used 'Knife Tool'. But now as you'll see in pic below, the edge-loop doesn't continue all the way around the edge I want it to. It in-fact only goes around the one corner  (pic:)
[image]

NOTE: Here is the correct one on the inside of the area... (NB. I'm new so not certain that even that is the correct way to make such edges in my models)..
[image]

ADDITIONAL: In trying to debug this, I notice the adjacent faces which I also cut with knife-tool are just registered as single faces still, this obviously what is causing my problem. (another pic...)
[image]

ADDITIONAL 2: I know see i could delete those faces and make two new ones in the place of the old ones. This has fixed the problem almost (ie. the outer side, of that outer-rim is now a complete separate edge loop). BUT - I still have issue where the loop carries through my junction on the X-Axis (note I have this problem on the inner edge and outer edge of the vent feature).... final pic attached here:
[image]

Any help hugely appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: maybe you have double vertices or inner faces you need to remove (double vertices: select all and W > Remove Doubles, inner faces: make your object transparent with Z, select the face and X > Face)

Comment: hi moonboots, thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly when I done 'Select All > Remove Doubles' I get alert saying "Removed 0 vertices". Just in case you didnt notice in my question, the one not working I cut with knife tool, the working one was by 'Inset'

Comment: ADDITIONAL: I notice in Face Select mode the faces adjacent (left and above - which I also cut with knife) are showing as one face still!! Im posting new screenshot now

Comment: oh ok so here is your problem, you need to delete this face and recreate two faces

Comment: thanks Moon!  I did that already to be honest, but I now have further problem. Please can you tell me is this normal and if not how can I fix the loop to go around the feature (... note one more new pic uploaded in a  moment :DD) thanks again

Comment: perhaps share your file, it will be easier  ;)  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure I would love to, i will arrange it right away thanks you!!!

Comment: All done Moonboots. REally appreciate all this help, thanks muchly. hopefully this last bit can be made as simple as the first parts u helped me with :D also post it as an answer if you like so I can quickly accept it

Comment: now I don't see anymore problem, you can create edge loops with ctrl R or with the knife, and the edge you've created on the X axis is perfectly normal, if you don't like the oblique and you want to make it straight you need to correct it manually with G G for example

Comment: ok thanks mate. I will try to figure it out from here. I've certainly got a lot further than when I started. Many thanks again , and if you want to post an answer about the trying of 'Remove Doubles' and checking all the faces are individual faces instead of just one with a edge running over the top (like was my problem), feel free and Ill accept it right away. Either way cheers for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84823/discussion-between-super-megabrobro-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone reads this in future with a similar confusion. The answer was that I had used 'F' to fill between the two vertices next to my knife cuts. But I didnt realise this didn't turn the one face into two. All I had to do was then delete them faces and make two there using the new edges. (hope that helps)